# Wordpress in docker on nginx - 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: nginx, docker-compose

The aim is to run `wordpress 4.7` with `php7` in docker. After some research I
found the following docker-compose.yml file. Unfortunately, when I start it, I
get a **502 bad gateway error** under `http://localhost:8080`.

Can anyone tell what the problem could be?

**my docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'

services:
  web:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - ./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    volumes_from:
      - wordpress
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:4.7.0-php7.0-fpm-alpine
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: example
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: mysql
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
```

**my site.conf file**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name localhost;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/html;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass wordpress:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try changing, from your nginx `site.conf` file the line `fastcgi_pass wordpress:9000;` to `fastcgi_pass web:9000;`